# Does Google Analytics track 404 page responses as valid page views?

Tags: google-analytics, 404, page-views

I'm interested to know what counts as a valid page view. I would assume a server status code in the 200 range would be valid. And anything 300, 400, 500 related would not be counted.

Can anyone confirm or point me to documentation that confirms this.

(I asked this question too Google but I get too many results on how to set up tracking for 404s. Which I don't want. Also I couldn't find it on the documentation, I kept getting results about handling 404 on the Data export api.)

I'm working with a single page application with short lived pages. I can see hits after the page expires which alludes me. I'm not sure how I'm getting hits days or weeks after it expires. Could it be browser caches are still executing the js and triggering a page view. If they are valid page views I should treat them as such in reports.

Comment: Do you have the tracking snippet installed on custom error pages?   GA only tracks pages for which you installed the GA JavaScript.   There is no way to install the tracking snippet on 300 statuses (redirects), but I suppose errors with actual pages might be possible to track in GA.

Answer (score 2):

So Stephen was right in the comments. If the tracking snippet is installed it tracks. Thinking about it further it makes sense, it executes client side, it'd be hard for it to retroactively look at the status code of the originally returned html.

Using a chrome plugin DataSlayer I was able to confirm the event is firing.

[image]

[image]